# Why it is not printing the magic square is magic?

Tags: java

I have to write a program that reads a file containing set of 16 numbers and creates a magic square. A magic square is one where the sum of each row, column, and diagonal is the same. I have to use the sentinel method to control your loop. The sentinel value is -999. When I run the code it shows that all are not magic square. When I run it it looks like the following.

1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8

9 10 11 12

13 14 15 16

NOT a magic square

1 15 14 4

12 6 7 9

8 10 11 5

13 3 2 16

NOT a magic square

30 8 20 11

3 10 21 35

24 25 13 7

12 26 15 16

NOT a magic square

14 8 19 92

37 53 16 27

67 10 54 2

15 62 44 12

NOT a magic square

2 5 6 1

8 5 2 9

4 5 6 7

3 2 7 5

NOT a magic square

The following is the code.

```
import java.io.File;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.Scanner;

class square {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        File data = new File("Lab8Data.txt");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(data);

        int[][] array = new int[4][4];
        int[] rowTotal = new int[4];
        int[] columnTotal = new int[4];

        for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++)

            array[0][row] = input.nextInt();

        while (array[0][0] != -999) {

            for (int column = 1; column < array.length; column++)

                for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++)

                    array[column][row] = input.nextInt();

            for (int column = 0; column < array.length; column++) {

                for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++)

                    System.out.print(array[column][row] + " ");

                System.out.println();

            }


            for (int column = 0; column < array.length; column++)

                for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++)

                    rowTotal[column] += array[column][row];



            for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++)

                for (int column = 0; column < array.length; column++)

                    columnTotal[row] += array[column][row];


            int diagonalOne = 0;
            for(int row = 0; row < array.length; row++)
                diagonalOne = diagonalOne + array[row][row];

            int otherDiagonal = 0;
            for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
                otherDiagonal = otherDiagonal + array[row][Math.abs(3 - row)];

                int rows = rowTotal[0];

                boolean rowEqual = true;

                for (int r = 0; r < array.length; r++)

                    if (rowTotal[r] != r)

                        rowEqual = false;

                int col = columnTotal[0];

                boolean columnEqual = true;

                for (int column = 0; column < array.length; column++)

                    if (rowTotal[column] != col)

                        columnEqual = false;

                int diagonal = diagonalOne;

                boolean diagonalEqual = true;

                if (otherDiagonal != diagonal)

                    diagonalEqual = false;

                boolean isMagic = false;

                if (rowEqual && columnEqual && diagonalEqual)

                    if (rows == col && col == diagonal)

                        isMagic = true;

                if (isMagic)

                    System.out.println("Is a magic square");

                else

                    System.out.println("NOT a magic square");

                for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++)

                    array[0][r] = input.nextInt();

            }

        }

    }
}
```

This should be a magic square.

1 15 14 4

12 6 7 9

8 10 11 5

13 3 2 16

What should I do to make it print if the square is magic correctly.

Comment: I don't see how this can be right: `if (rowTotal[r] != r)`  In a magic square, all totals are the same, right?  But here's you're checking if the row total is the same as the index value (0, 1, 2, ...) which would make all the rows different.  I think you need to go back and re-think your logic.

Answer (score 0):

I initialize the variables inside the loop, otherwise the totals will not be correct:

```
    while (true) {
        int[][] array = new int[4][4];
        int[] rowTotal = new int[4];
        int[] columnTotal = new int[4];
```

the first number you read is either the sentinel, or array[0][0]:

```
        int number = input.nextInt();
        if (number == -999) {
            break;
        }
        array[0][0] = number;
```

Now you need to read the remainder of row 0:

```
        for (int column = 1; column < array[0].length; column++) {
            array[0][column] = input.nextInt();
        }
```

and then the other rows:

```
        for (int row = 1; row < array.length; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < array[row].length; column++) {
                array[row][column] = input.nextInt();
            }
        }
```

Now, the calculations; column totals:

```
        for (int column = 0; column < array.length; column++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
                columnTotal[column] += array[row][column];
            }
        }
```

row totals:

```
        for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < array.length; column++) {
                rowTotal[row] += array[row][column];
            }
        }
```

diagonals:

```
        int diagonalOne = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
            diagonalOne += array[row][row];
        }

        int otherDiagonal = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
            otherDiagonal += array[row][array.length - row - 1];
        }
```

then the comparisons:

```
        int row = rowTotal[0];

        boolean rowEqual = true;

        for (int r = 0; r < array.length; r++) {
            if (rowTotal[r] != row) {
                rowEqual = false;
            }
        }

        int col = columnTotal[0];

        boolean columnEqual = true;

        for (int column = 0; column < array.length; column++) {
            if (columnTotal[column] != col) {
                columnEqual = false;
            }
        }

        int diagonal = diagonalOne;

        boolean diagonalEqual = true;

        if (otherDiagonal != diagonal) {
            diagonalEqual = false;
        }

        boolean isMagic = false;

        if (rowEqual && columnEqual && diagonalEqual) {
            if (row == col && col == diagonal) {
                isMagic = true;
            }
        }

        if (isMagic) {
            System.out.println("Is a magic square");
        } else {
            System.out.println("NOT a magic square");
        }
```

Of course you wouldn't need to store the totals in arrays: you could just compare them as you compute them.

```
        int sum = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
            sum += array[row][row];
        }

        boolean isMagic = true;
        int magicNumber = sum;

        sum = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
            sum += array[row][array.length - row - 1];
        }

        if (sum != magicNumber) {
            isMagic = false;
        }

        for (int column = 0; column < array.length; column++) {
            sum = 0;
            for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
                sum += array[row][column];
            }
            if (sum != magicNumber) {
                isMagic = false;
            }
        }

        for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
            sum = 0;
            for (int column = 0; column < array.length; column++) {
                sum += array[row][column];
            }
            if (sum != magicNumber) {
                isMagic = false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("Lab8Data.txt");
        int[][] square = readSquareFromFile(file);
        boolean magicSquare = isMagicSquare(square);
        System.out.println(magicSquare);
    }

    private static int[][] readSquareFromFile(File file) {
        // TODO read from file
        return new int[][] {
                { 1, 15, 14, 4 },
                { 12, 6, 7, 9 },
                { 8, 10, 11, 5 },
                { 13, 3, 2, 16 } };
    }

    private static boolean isMagicSquare(int[][] square) {
        int magicNumber = Arrays.stream(square[0]).sum();
        return isRowsMagic(square, magicNumber)
                && isColumnsMagic(square, magicNumber)
                && isDiagonalsMagic(square, magicNumber);
    }

    private static boolean isRowsMagic(int[][] square, int magicNumber) {
        for (int row = 0; row < square.length; row++) {
            int sum = 0;

            for (int col = 0; col < square[row].length; col++)
                sum += square[row][col];

            if (sum != magicNumber)
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private static boolean isColumnsMagic(int[][] square, int magicNumber) {
        for (int col = 0; col < square[0].length; col++) {
            int sum = 0;

            for (int row = 0; row < square.length; row++)
                sum += square[row][col];

            if (sum != magicNumber)
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private static boolean isDiagonalsMagic(int[][] square, int magicNumber) {
        return getLeftDiagonalSum(square) == magicNumber && getRightDiagonalSum(square) == magicNumber;
    }

    private static int getLeftDiagonalSum(int[][] square) {
        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < square.length; i++)
            sum += square[i][i];

        return sum;
    }

    private static int getRightDiagonalSum(int[][] square) {
        int sum = 0;

        for (int row = 0, col = square.length - 1; row < square.length; row++, col--)
            sum += square[row][col];

        return sum;
    }

}
```